# Vuforia basic app sample for android

Tags: android, vuforia

I want to know if anyone has an idea where to find basic android samples for vuforia sdk because provided samples are too big for me to fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples provide several examples - focus on the most simple one, which is ImageTargets (.java + renderer), and this is pretty much as minimal as you can find.